# GWT JUnit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, junit

I'm trying a very JUnit Testing for GWT put it is failing

```
public class CheckTest extends TestCase
{

    private ServiceAsync RPC;
    private HandlerManager EventBus;
    private CreateTopicPresenter.Display CTV;
    private CreateTopicPresenter CTP;

    protected void setUp() 
    {
        RPC= createStrictMock(ServiceAsync.class);
        EventBus = new HandlerManager(null);
        CTV= createStrictMock(CreateTopicView.class);
        CTP= new CreateTopicPresenter(CTV,RPC,EventBus);
    }
    public void testCheck()
    {

        CTP.View.getFirstMessage().setValue("MessageTest");
        assertTrue(CTP.View.getFirstMessage().getValue().equals("MessageTest"));
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:619)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:612)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerCallbacks(Enhancer.java:581)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:194)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:60)
        at org.easymock.EasyMock.createStrictMock(EasyMock.java:70)
        at com.BiddingSystem.client.CheckTest.setUp(CheckTest.java:26)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:128)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
        at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:91)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.<clinit>(UIObject.java:188)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extend the GWTTestCase base type in order to test code that depends on the GWT runtime (e.g. calls to GWT.create() or JSNI methods).  Note that the GWTTestCase must be GWT-compatible as well, so this will limit your choice of testing libraries.

Ideally, most of your app code is testable with "pure" TestCases, with only client-specific code being tested by GWTTestCases, since the latter have a higher overhead.

http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/testing_methodologies_using_gwt.html

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the standard jUnit test runner doesn't handle GWT runtime, as mentioned in BobV's answer. His solution may be the easiest to run out of the box, but if you are using other frameworks such as Mockito, this may not be the easiest solution. There are also some oddities that I've found when extending `GWTTestCase`.

The way I prefer to do it is to head the class with the `@RunWith([SomeTestRunner].class)` annotation. For example, [GWT Mockito](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito) comes with its own test runner, so using that is a lot more streamlined than extending `GWTTestCase` in that it allows you to not have to rewrite any parent class that your test case may extend.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases calling **GWTMockUtilities.disarm()** at the beginning of the test, *that replaces the normal GWT.create() behavior with a method that returns null instead of throwing a runtime exception*, enables writing pure JUnit test(not GWTTestCase) for GWT code.

This approach can be helpful only in situations when class under test doesn't require object that is created with GWT.create()